# Get input value in JavaScript without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have an input field like this:

```
<input type="text" id="input" value="This is my value">
```

How can I get the attribute value? In jQuery, I can easily get it with:

```
$('#input').val() //-> This is my value
```

How do I do so using pure JavaScript?

Comment: Must be one of the most viewed questions on SO and you couldnt find it?

Comment: cheap reputation time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can get the value by targeting the ID.
Where `inputID` is the **ID** of your input or textarea:

```
document.getElementById('inputID').value;
```

You can also do it by targeting the name attribute. 
Where `inputID` is the **Name** of your input or textarea:

```
document.getElementsByName('inputID')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 3):

The element must have an ID

```
<input type="text" id="text-field-id" value="A test!">
```

And then you do this:

```
var value = document.getElementById('text-field-id').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) , to get value use `value` property

```
<input type-"text" id="text" />

var text=document.getElementById('text').value;
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/56XJk/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("input-id").value
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, everything that is written in jQuery can be written in pure Javascript

```
var value = document.querySelector('#yourInput').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
<input type="hidden" id="yourID" name="msg" value="" style="display:none"/>

var Msg="abc";
document.getElementById('yourID').value = Msg;
```